# Clone an EMR Notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

Since [multi-users access is not possible in EMR Notebooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-working-with.html#emr-managed-notebooks-editor:%7E:text=Only%20one%20user%20can%20have%20an,is%20already%20open%2C%20an%20error%20occurs.), I'm wondering if it's possible to clone an existing notebook to enable developers to work in parallel instead of having to wait for each other to finish in order to get access to that notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of cloning or downloading the notebook, I will suggest to [associate Git-based repositories](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-git-repo.html) with your Amazon EMR notebooks to save your notebooks.

In Amazon EMR console,Choose Git repositories, and then choose Add repository and follow the steps.

You can find the detailed [precedure here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-git-repo-add.html).

Update on the question:

Yes, You can clone or merge code from/to remote Git repositories directly from your notebook. You can use this command for pulling/pushing within the notebook itself as well.

```
!git pull origin master
```

On running this for example, you will be able to see the files/notebooks from the repository to work on in the files navigation in both `jupyterlab`/`jupyter-notebook`

Comment: Does this method allow importing a template notebook from the repository directly to EMR? The end goal here is for developers to clone a notebook and work on separate pieces to accelerate the workflow.

Comment: I have updated the answer, feel free to upvote or accept it as an answer if it helped.